# how to select all rows in MySQL workbench in ubuntu

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to delete all rows content from my database using MySQL workbench in my ubuntu openrating system. How can i do this. Ctrl+A is not working

Comment: That's weird, `Ctrl+A` is supposed to work (I've only tested on Windows though).

Answer (score 0):

It would be much simpler if you just run a TRUNCATE query on your tables.